# redux bindActionCreators any action is dispached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

after 20 hours of test i can not understand where i mistake.

all work fine if i use a storeredux dispacth, but now i will use action with bindActionCreators

this is my action

```
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux"
import store from "../Store/Store";
export const action = {
login:function(payload) {
    console.log("i'm here");
    return {
    type:"AUTH_LOGIN",
    payload
    }
    //this work!!
    // store.dispatch({
    //                 type:"AUTH_LOGIN",
    //                 payload
    //             })
    }
}
export const actionAuth = bindActionCreators(action, store.dispatch);
```

the component

```
class Login extends Component {
    login(type, username, password) {
        actionAuth.login({
                        typeauth:type,
                         username:username,
                         password:password
                     })
    }
    render(){
      return(<button onclick={()=>{this.login("ok","user,"pwd");}}>click</button>)
     }
  }

   const selector=createSelector(
    (state)=>{return state.auth},
(auth)=>{return auth.toJS()}
  );
  function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
      ...selector(state)
      }}
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login)
```

in component or in action if i use store.dispatch i see work all fine, but not work if i try use actionAuth.login

where i mistake?i can not understand

Comment: when i call actionAuth.login the phrase "i'm here" is writed in console.

Answer (score 0):

the problem (i not understand why!) the name of const "action"

```
export const _action_ = {...}
export const actionAuth = bindActionCreators(_action_, store.dispatch);
//now work fine!!!
```